# Changing border style in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, style, mapnik

I am trying to figure out how to change OpenStreetMap country borders color/thickness.

I've set up a tile server using OSM data, PostgreSQL & Mapnik.

The default mapnik style is used.

There doesn't seem to be a straight forward way to do it globally.

I'm a newbie.